# Getting largest values from different arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get the largest values from different arrays. Basically, the arrays are populated from 3 different websites, and I need to know what are the largest `tags` and `photos` values of each product.

**I have the following array:**

```
$data = array(
    'domain1.com' => array(
        'id1' => array(
            'tags' => '5',
            'photos' => '4',
        ),
        'id2' => array(
            'tags' => '8',
            'photos' => '2',
        ),
        'id3' => array(
            'tags' => '6',
            'photos' => '1',
        ),
    ),
    'domain2.com' => array(
        'id1' => array(
            'tags' => '3',
            'photos' => '1',
        ),
        'id2' => array(
            'tags' => '4',
            'photos' => '9',
        ),
        'id3' => array(
            'tags' => '2',
            'photos' => '0',
        ),
    ),
    'domain3.com' => array(
        'id1' => array(
            'tags' => '7',
            'photos' => '3',
        ),
        'id2' => array(
            'tags' => '9',
            'photos' => '5',
        ),
        'id3' => array(
            'tags' => '2',
            'photos' => '4',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**I need to get the following result:**

```
$data = array(
    'id1' => array(
        'tags' => '7',
        'photos' => '4',
    ),
    'id2' => array(
        'tags' => '9',
        'photos' => '9',
    ),
    'id3' => array(
        'tags' => '6',
        'photos' => '4',
    ),
);
```

Comment: That's great, so what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried `array_merge` and `array_combine`, but it seems they're not the one I need to use [taken from php.net].

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot, it worked! :-)

Comment: Are you fetching this data from a database?  If so, post your query and we can find out an even faster way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solveable with a simple loop:

```
$new = array();

foreach($data as $domain){
    foreach($domain as $id => $_data){
        foreach($_data as $elem => $value) { 
            if(!isset($new[$id][$elem]) || $value > $new[$id][$elem]){
                $new[$id][$elem] = $value;
            } 
        }
    }    
}
```

Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [id1] => Array
        (
            [tags] => 7
            [photos] => 4
        )

    [id2] => Array
        (
            [tags] => 9
            [photos] => 9
        )

    [id3] => Array
        (
            [tags] => 6
            [photos] => 4
        )

)
```

[<kbd>**Example**</kbd>](http://www.tehplayground.com/#teLosXK1q)

Comment: Actually, that's the easiest way! And faster, I've just tested it. I'll use yours, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use nested foreach loops to iterate and capture the data. The results are updated if there is a higher value found in the results array.

```
$results = [];
foreach ($data as $domain => $items) {
    foreach ($items as $id => $elements) {
        if (!isset($results[ $id ])) {
            $results[ $id ] = [];
        }
        foreach ($elements as $tag => $value) {
            if (!isset($results[ $id ][ $tag ]) || $value>$results[ $id ][ $tag ]) {
                $results[ $id ][ $tag ] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($results);
```